# Negative Balance terminologies

Tags: credit-card, financial-literacy

When your CC balance turns negative, then it's an overdraft right? What are the other terms for Negative Balance / Overdraft?

Comment: overdraft is a term for checking accounts, not credit card accounts. Cards linked to checking accounts are usually called debit cards. What your asking here is very unclear, likely due to the confusion of some of these terms.

Comment: An overdraft is when you've gone "in to negative". That's the opposite of what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

> When your CC balance turns negative, then it's an overdraft right?

No.  It means that you've paid more against your loan than you needed to.  They now owe you money (or won't charge interest on charges that you make).

That makes it an asset of yours, which is the exact opposite of an overdraft.